# Videos from Amazon Server returns erron on AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, avfoundation, avplayer

I have an video app and I had an issue. When I play videos about 5-15 times, It starts not playing the videos. It returns; "You do not have permission to access the requested resource." Then AVPlayer goes black screen and does anything happens. When I pop the PlayVideoViewController and go forward, the video that is given black screen starts to play.

Is there anyone faced this issue? Is there any configuration should I change on Amazon or iOS part?

Thanks in advance.